# Embed external web application with script into multiple websites

Tags: javascript, angular, embed

I have implemented many third party apps where the vendor provides me a snippet of code that I just need to place on a page in the website.

What are some ways to do that?  Specifically, can an angular2 application be injected in such a manner?

I am building an application and would like to provide the clients the script tag(s), along with validation credentials to place directly on their site and the site would load in the container element on the page and look as it was part of their site.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is frequently done with the `iframe` element. Check out this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).